# SVG/Angular: rings with different shade

Tags: angular, svg

I was looking for a solution that draws rings and make every ring with a different shade.

The result is what I want ... but I have no idea why it is working. I would expect every ring with the SAME color.

???

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `

<svg [attr.height]="dimension" [attr.width]="dimension" [attr.viewBox]="'-' + dimension + ' -' + dimension + ' ' + dimension * 2 + ' ' + dimension * 2">
 <circle [attr.cx]="0" [attr.cy]="0" [attr.r]="dimension" [attr.fill]="foo()"><title>{{ foo () }}</title></circle>
 <circle [attr.cx]="0" [attr.cy]="0" [attr.r]="dimension/100*50" [attr.fill]="foo ()"><title>{{ foo () }}</title></circle>
 <circle [attr.cx]="0" [attr.cy]="0" [attr.r]="dimension/100*10" [attr.fill]="foo ()"><title>{{ foo () }}</title></circle>
</svg>
`
})
export class AppComponent
{
  dimension : number = 500;


  foo ()
  {
    return "#" + 0xBBAABB;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the three circles are overlapping each other in certain areas, thus produces the different shades. If you try to separate those 3 circles in their own svg, you will find them having the same color.

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwlzfk?file=src/app/app.component.html) I created.

Comment: I was not aware fill-color does is affected by the background.

Comment: Yes, it does affect the fill color.

Comment: Can you tell me if I can make the fill 100% overlapping without this effekt?

Comment: Did some tests and it seems it is not always overlapping. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69312736/angular-svg-fill-darkens-or-overlaps

Comment: Yes, I saw your question. The reason that it is not working is because you are not using a color with transparency. For example: the hex color of light green is #90EE90, if you try to add it directly in your svg fill, it won't work as expected. You can add 80 at the end of that hex to make it transparent. Check your fill color as well in your original code, it is using a different hex with transparency compared to #AAAAAA which you are using in your bar() function.