# Angular/SVG: Fill darkens or overlaps?

Tags: angular, svg

I have a SVG in Angular and I am not sure how the filling works.

foo does overlap and darkens each circle, bar does not.
To me it seems both should produce the same result.

???

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dog597?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I suspect your previous question is actually answered by this answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'#' + 0xaaaaaa; serialises to #11184810 because the value 0xaaaaaa is converted to decimal you can see that if you add something like console.log('#' + 0xaaaaaa);

then 11184810 is interpreted as hex rgba by the browser i.e. red = 11, green = 18, blue = 48 and alpha = 10.

I guess what you really want is something like this perhaps...

```js
console.log('#' + 0xaaaaaa.toString(16));
```